# Excel - Is it possible to make the OFFSET function skip hidden cells

Tags: excel, vba, function, offset

I have a very simple OFFSET Function that i connect to a scroll bar to scroll through data. `=OFFSET(A$2,$A$48,0)`. When I filter the data in cells A2-A45 to select only a certain category, i'd like the scrolling of the OFFSET function to skip the hidden cells and only scroll through the data that is still visible after filtering.

```
Sub AddVisibleName()

    Dim rVisible As Range
    Dim lLastRow As Long

    lLastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rVisible = Range("A2:A45" & lLastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="VisibleRange", RefersTo:=rVisible

End Sub
```

The code above creates the range "VisibleRange" that only has the values of the non hidden cells shown in it. Is there a way to incorporate this into the OFFSET function?

Any other simpler methods of achieving what i'd like are also welcomed

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
Sub Macro1() 

    If Rows("1:10").EntireRow.Hidden = True Then 
        Rows("1:10").EntireRow.Hidden = False 
    ElseIf Columns("2:3").EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then 
        Columns("2:3").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 
    End If 

End Sub
```

Or, this?

```
For i = 2 To 20 

    If Not Rows(i).Hidden 

     'do stuff
End If 
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Worked for me.

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Height <> 0
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
```